# CLR error when printing

Tags: c#, printing

I have a project in c# and it crashes (always) on the 11th print. It works well otherwise. I have looked through the web but there does not seem to be a definitive answer. It does this in both debug and release modes and it is for x86.

It is being call by 
     var Printinstance = new Printing_Form(); 
     Printinstance.PrintCard();

```
using System; 
using System.Drawing.Printing; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.ComponentModel; 

namespace COM_Caller_CS 
{ 
public class Printing_Form 
{ 
public void PrintCard() 
{
    PrintDocument ppd = new PrintDocument();

    ppd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Card", 340, 210);
    ppd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ppd_PrintPage);
    ppd.Print();
}


private static void ppd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    string spare = "";
    int numvalue = Convert.ToInt32(Global.Global_PN);
    try
    {
        if (Global.GUPprintingposition != "Do Not Print")
        {
            TypeConverter converter2 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Point));
            Point point2 = (Point)converter2.ConvertFromString(Global.GUPprintingposition);
            ev.Graphics.DrawString("Test Image", new Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, point2);
        }
        if (Global.printnumberbool == true)
        {
            if (Global.printingposition != "Do Not Print")
            {
                TypeConverter converter1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Point));
                Point point1 = (Point)converter1.ConvertFromString(Global.printingposition);
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(spare + (Global.Global_PrintPN), new Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, point1);
            }
        }
        if (Global.Global_pnamebool == true)
        {
            StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 50, 340, 210);
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(Global.Global_pname, new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, rect1, stringFormat);
        }

        if (Global.printlogobool == true)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Global.Global_Path);
            Point loc = new Point(5, 10);
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 10, 195, 114, 10);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error, Application with now Close", ex.ToString());
        Application.Exit();
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

I made the suggested changes and I get "System.ExecutionEngineException" occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DLL

Comment: It would help if you included the exception message.  How do you get to 11 pages?  It looks like it prints once.  Dispose your images when you're done with them.

Comment: Sorry for the failure. Yes, it does print once at a time (in a loop). I am customizing cards so each card is personalized.

The error message is:  APPCRASH Application Name: Test.exe Application Version: 1.0.0.0 Application Timestamp: 5a7ceb69 Fault Module Name: clr.dll Fault Module Version: 4.7.2053.0 Fault Module Timestamp: 58fa6bb3 Exception Code: c0000005 Exception Offset: 0002d78e OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 Locale ID: 1033 Additional Information 1: 12c0 Additional Information 2: 12c095676d2a7ddc356d662ef57865fd Additional Information 3: fd13

Comment: That message is when running the exe outside.

Comment: In VS I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: `ExecutionEngineException` is a pretty serious exception.  Which line of code does it die on?  Are you sure the posted code is causing the exception?  You have a lot of "global" variables and calls — that's not a good sign.

Comment: It is dying on ppd.print();

Comment: There has to be more code around that block.

Comment: This is all I have left out...                                                                    
using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace COM_Caller_CS
{
    public class Printing_Form
    {
        public void PrintCard()                                                                              It is being call by  var Printinstance = new Printing_Form();
                               Printinstance.PrintCard();

Comment: @ J C      I'll try it and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for sharing the code. From the snippet above some things I understand are:

-This looks like a Java code — based on your function declarations :) that's what they're called in C. You don't have to initiate functions in C.

— Your code is probably even running because you're running it in an IDE and not on a pure C compiler. Borland C etc. etc. :)

— So if there're no command line errors and this's a runtime error, it'll be interesting to know what you mean by "crashes". Does it exit smoothly or does it give you a runtime error? Try adding an end message like *"Finished printing." point2 *

—I can't see the arguments being passed in the first block of your snippet.

— But more than anything you're not attempting to print serially.The *Point loc = new Point(5, 10);* argument is giving the page number— you're calling it "loc". It's a beginning and end point — that is page range.

—It's seems to be instructing to print pages 5 through 10. If the program is making a clean exit, then it must be printing pages 5 through 10 and terminating.

Also, this's just a stylistic preference, but I'd keep the formatting data separate by storing Font into a variable Font1 or something like that and then just pass it as a parameter.

*ev.Graphics.DrawString(Global.Global_pname, *new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular),* Brushes.Black, rect1, stringFormat);*

could be written as:

*Font Font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);

ev.Graphics.DrawString(Global.Global_pname, Font1, Brushes.Black, rect1, stringFormat);*

Much cleaner.

— Also, you are providing the page range here *Point loc = new Point(5, 10)*. Do you intend to allow users to input page range values later as an update?

Comment: There is nothing in the post to indicate this is java.  The first sentence even says "I have a project in c#".